# javascript and css transition property won't work on firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using a Slide in menu script on browser from here [Slide in menu](http://cubiq.org/slide-in-menu). I have followed all the instruction as given.Finally it has started working but only on chrome and safari browser,
    But my main target is to get it start on Firefox, I have tried several things by changing some CSS and modifying the JavaScript,
    In the JavaScript I have given alert() to test exactly it is moving inside the script or not, and I found that all the alerts are executed in perfect sequence.
  I am not getting any hint why this thing happened.
Below is the code with html page , JavaScript and css

html page

```
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/new.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slideinmenu.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
var menu;
function loaded() {
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); 

e.stopPropagation(); });
    menu = new slideInMenu('slidedownmenu', true);
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="slidedownmenu">
    <ul>
        <li>Option 1</li>
        <li>Option 2</li>
        <li>Option 3</li>
        <li>Option 4</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="handle"></div>
</div>

<div id="content">


    <p>Click to <a href="#" onclick="menu.open();return false">Open</a>, <a 

href="#" onclick="menu.close();return false">Close</a> and <a href="#" 

onclick="menu.toggle();return false">Toggle</a> the menu programmatically.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

the JavaScript

```
 function slideInMenu (el, opened) {
    this.container = document.getElementById(el);
    this.handle = this.container.querySelector('.handle');
    this.openedPosition = this.container.clientHeight;
    this.container.style.opacity = '1';
    this.container.style.top = '-' + this.openedPosition + 'px';
    this.container.style.webkitTransitionProperty = '-webkit-transform';
    this.container.style.webkitTransitionDuration = '400ms';
    if ( opened===true ) {
        this.open();
    }
    this.handle.addEventListener('touchstart', this);
}
slideInMenu.prototype = {
    pos: 0,
    opened: false,
    handleEvent: function(e) {
        switch (e.type) {
            case 'touchstart': this.touchStart(e); break;
            case 'touchmove': this.touchMove(e); break;
            case 'touchend': this.touchEnd(e); break;
        }       
    },
    setPosition: function(pos) {
        this.pos = pos;
        this.container.style.webkitTransform = 'translate(0,' + pos + 'px)';
        if (this.pos == this.openedPosition) {
            this.opened = true;
        } else if (this.pos == 0) {
            this.opened = false;
        }
    },
    open: function() {
        this.setPosition(this.openedPosition);
    },
    close: function() {
        this.setPosition("0");
    },
    toggle: function() {
        if (this.opened) {
            this.close();
        } else {
            this.open();
        }
    }
}
```

CSS

```
    a{
    color:#ffc;
}
ul, li, div {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}
#content {
    padding:40px 10px 10px 10px;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:0 1px 1px #000;
    font-size:1.2em;
}
#slidedownmenu {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:115px;
    left:0;
    background:black url(drawer-bg.jpg);
}
#slidedownmenu .handle {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-28px;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:28px;
    border-top:1px solid #532500;
    border-bottom:1px solid #111;
    background-color:maroon;
    background:url(handle.png) no-repeat 50% 50%, -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, color-stop(0, #e07b29), color-stop(0.1, #b85300), color-stop(0.8, #793600));
/*  -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);*/
}
#slidedownmenu ul {
    display:block;
    width:auto;
}
#slidedownmenu li {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin:20px 10px;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow:0 1px 1px #000;
}
```

Any type of suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: see all those things that start with `webkit` or `-webkit-` - they only work on chrome/safari - you need to use the non prefixed versions of those styles to work in every other browser on the planet

Comment: Can you try using -moz-transform in here: this.container.style.webkitTransitionProperty = '-webkit-transform';

Comment: -moz-transform over there not working..but chromes still seems to work properly with even -moz-transform.

Comment: For which platform are you building this menu?

Comment: Its a browser based PHP application in which i want add this menu and even it would be working on android browsers and iOS browser.And even in Android, Firefox browser showing the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution for above issue,Actually yes the webkit is for safari but standard syntax are supported by Firefox,chrome,Internet-Explorer 10, that is, In above JavaScript

```
   this.container.style.webkitTransitionProperty = '-webkit-transform';
```

replaced with

```
  this.container.style.transitionProperty = 'transform';
```

Similarly

```
  this.container.style.webkitTransitionDuration = '400ms';
```

to

```
  this.container.style.transitionDuration = '400ms';
```

and

```
this.container.style.webkitTransform = 'translate(0,' + pos + 'px)';
```

to

```
this.container.style.transform = 'translate(0,' + pos + 'px)';
```

and its ready for Firefox desktop browser.

Basically, now I have followed the standard syntax,rather than using webkit which is working perfectly fine in Firefox desktop browser.Firefox supports standard style syntax, So according to this search when transitions not working on Firefox simply use the standard syntax for css if you want to get it work on Firefox,I tested it and its working like a charm on desktop Firefox but not smoothly on mobile Firefox browser.

Answer (score -2):

try to remove the `/*` `*/` from the webkit line (hope it works)and I found its not yet available for all the browsers

Comment: You mean to enable webkit? I believe that won't work (just tried it). Can you please explain.

Comment: yes enable webkit and mozkit .. try to update firefox or just report an issue to firefox community .. may be its due to browser build